# A user said they awarded my answer by mistake, and asked me to award a bounty on the other answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, code-of-conduct

Okay, so weird situation:

A user said they accidentally [awarded me a 100 rep bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67528559/13552470), that they intended to give it to [the other answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482048/13552470). They [asked me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452824/find-string-between-two-substrings-in-a-stream-of-data/67482048?noredirect=1#comment119491575_67482048) to give a 50 bounty to the other answerer, and I thought:

> *[Sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452824/find-string-between-two-substrings-in-a-stream-of-data/67482048?noredirect=1#comment119491783_67482048)! I can the offer the 50 rep bounty on a different question where the answerer provided [a worthy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67438558/13552470).*

But I'm wondering if it's allowed, to place a bounty on a question arguably just to transfer rep. I don't want anyone to get in trouble for what I see as an honest mistake. What is the best course of action in this situation?

Comment: Do nothing, it's not your responsibility.

Comment: "just to transfer rep" is basically what a bounty ***is***. It's really up to you. Either keep the 100 to yourself or comply and transfer the 50/100 to the asked user. I don't see how we can help...

Comment: @Tomerikoo https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8878267#8878267

Comment: But they're not asking you to do it "just to transfer rep"!, they're asking you to reward what they think is a good answer. quoting from their comment *"but his answer helped completely, and it was the first"* - You're passing it off like they've done something wrong when they haven't. Unless you're asking if it's okay for _you_ to do it, in which case, it's your rep!, you can choose whether or not the answer they want to have bountied is good/bad.

Comment: @AnnZen https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8878308#8878308 :)

Comment: So it seems like you got your answer... Although I don't fully agree with that as offering a bounty "just to transfer rep" to someone whose answer helped you is quite common. Anyway, this is a special case. It's not as if you just feel like transferring to someone else with no reason...

Comment: @Nick No, if it's wrong then what about https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407758/a-user-said-they-awarded-my-answer-by-mistake-and-asked-me-to-award-a-bounty-on?noredirect=1#comment843826_407758

Comment: @Tomerikoo *"So it seems like you got your answer."* No, I have this to consider: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8878312#8878312

Comment: Ultimately the rep is yours, they want you to reward an answer for being good, if you want to bounty, go for it. Otherwise, the comment is no longer needed, flag it as such and move on

Comment: Still, bottom line is - it's your own moral dilemma. If someone gave you 100$ and then told you it was meant for someone else - will you give it to them or not?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sure I would. But a bounty is not as simple as "giving" rep; if 2 users continuously "give" each others rep, it could be seen as abusing the bounty system to get more attention on their posts.

Comment: Careful! Maybe they are trying to use you to unwittingly launder reputation!!! /s

Comment: @yivi oh no, it must be the secret underground reputation mafia!

Comment: There's no reason you should pay to advertise their question. Even posting this meta question is giving un-due advertising to it.

Comment: Look at it this way: You got free reputation! Keep it! Reputation is not money, it's fake internet points, and it's the OP's fault if they "accidentally" rewarded the bounty to the wrong person. (It's really hard to accidentally give it to the wrong person, I've given bounties on other sites, so I should know).

Comment: Voting rings use rep transfer through bounties as a means of reputation points laundering (as they will not lose the reputation points when the voting accounts are destroyed).

Comment: @Zoe: From what I have observed on many occasions, I don't think it is far off.

Comment: @KevinB I was talking about this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67438558/13552470

Comment: If you feel 'guilty' about the reputation you were mistakenly awarded, then you could always donate (some of) it to charity. Here's a [worthy cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/10871073). :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with your reputation and the bounties you can offer.

But whatever you do make sure it is **your** decision to start a bounty and it is **your** decision which answer to select.

Do not let yourself feel pressured by anyone to offer bounties.

If you're being harassed for not complying to demands / requests do flag for a moderator. If that happens off-site, use the Contact Us form.

I have a ton of awesome answers both on SO proper and MSE. Please  give me all your reputation. In exchange I'm okay if you don't accept this answer.

Comment: I personally would ignore such a request, I might even just randomly start a bounty to a random question, and specifically allow the system to automatically reward the bounty. Of course I have a German mindset, I am more stubborn than my Schnauzer at times, so I do stuff like that.

Comment: @SecurityHound Ha! Please give your Schnauzer a *Hundekeks* and a friendly pat from me ...

Comment: My schnauzer is embarrassed he had to look up what a hundekek was.  Once he consulted the German Sheperd next door the plotted ways to their cookie.